# Getting ng-options value from Map in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: angularjs, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to populate a select using ng-otions from a HashMap. I am not getting anything in output

I have tried this, but it does not work. However, it works on a Array of String

```
<select ng-model="group" ng-options="key for (key, g) in groups"></select>
```

I have checked the angular binding and everything is in place.

As a backup, I created a array of delimited String but then I am not able to split each string into key and value